# Access Localhost from within container with Docker Stack

Tags: docker, docker-stack

I have a VM running in Azure, that I'm trying to connect to a port on the VM from within a container.

just running the container, I can do something like `docker run -it --net="host" managed-service-identity` this works as expected.

How can I replicate that under docker stack?

Comment: what is the message you're getting when trying to run the container on the stack?

Comment: @omu_negru it gives a `net Additional property net is not allowed` when adding `net: host` into the services of the docker-compose file